# Restkit 10.0: What's new

Tags: restkit

What`s new with the RestKit-release? Should I update? Where are the changes documented?

I can not find any information on the several news channels: website, github, twitter, google groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is on github.](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.9.3-to-0.10.0)
And describes in general terms the changes.

I would suggest if you are in active development you should upgrade, if you are maintaining something and have no problems with Restkit I would leave as is until you able to fully test with the new version.

Answer (score 0):

http://restkit.org/api/ This page will give you API documents. 
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0 - Upgrading from v0.10.x to v0.20.0